# Last two bins have same number of balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we throw $n$ balls independently and randomly into $n$ bins, what is the probability that the last two bins have an equal number of balls?

We can write that as the sum of the probability that each of the last two bins has $i$ balls, for $0\leq i\leq n/2$, and add them up. But how to calculate each of these probabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us generalize slightly and assume that we are throwing $b$ balls. With suitable restrictions on $i+j$, the probability the next to last bin has $i$ balls and the last has $j$ is
$$\frac{b!}{i!j!(b-i-j)!}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^i\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^j\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^{b-i-j}.$$
We have used the *multinomial distribution*. The reasoning is much like the one for the binomial distribution. The first term is the number of ways of making a word of length $b$, with $i$ occurrences of the letter N (next to last), $j$ occurrences of the letter L (last), and $b-i-j$ occurrences of the letter O (other).